# Setting date/time on a unix based server with Python (Paramiko module)

Tags: python, datetime, paramiko

Okay, can someone tell what I'm doing wrong with this simple request to change the time? I'm on a win 7 machine, trying to change the time on a linux box. I can login, search logs and run other commands, of course adjusting my code below. But this simple command is not changing the date/time. I must be overlooking something?

```
datetime_string = raw_input("Enter date and time in format 11/1/2011 1600")    

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(iP_address, username='root', password='******')
apath = '/'
apattern = datetime_string
rawcommand = 'date -s' + datetime_string
command1 = rawcommand.format(pattern=apattern)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command1)
dateresult = stdout.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Can you put `print command1` in there and show the actual command string?

Comment: related: [Fabric](http://fabfile.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
rawcommand = 'date -s' + datetime_string
```

To this:

```
rawcommand = 'date -s "%s"' % datetime_string
```

And im not positive, but I dont think `rawcommand.format(pattern=apattern)` is necessary:

```
datetime_string = raw_input("Enter date and time in format 11/1/2011 1600")
command1 = 'date -s "%s"' % datetime_string
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command1)
dateresult = stdout.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: It still didn't work. I can't figure out why not. The same command on the unix shell works flawlessly, and other commands from Python script w/ similar code on windows work flawlessly. SMH

Comment: im not positive, but I dont think `rawcommand.format(pattern=apattern)` is necessary.  See my edit.

Comment: The space makes no difference.

Comment: The above edit works. Putting quotes around a variable would not work.

Comment: It might be bad to pass an unescaped user input to a shell `'11/1/2011 1600"; rm -rf "/'`. [It is easy to validate it in this case.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960199/setting-date-time-on-a-unix-based-server-with-python-paramiko-module/7960649#7960649)

Answer (score 1):

You should validate user input. Especially if it might be passed unescaped to the shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

import paramiko

# read new date from stdin
datetime_format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M"
newdate_string = raw_input("Enter date and time in format 11/1/2011 1600")    

# validate that newdate string is in datetime_format
newdate = datetime.strptime(newdate_string, datetime_format)

# print date (change it to `-s` to set the date)
command = "date -d '%s'" % newdate.strftime(datetime_format)

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("localhost") # use ssh keys to authenticate
# run it
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdin.close()

# get output of the command
print
print "stdout: %r" % (stdout.read(),)
print '*'*79
print "stderr: %r" % (stderr.read(),)
```

#### Output

```
$ echo 1/11/2011 1600 | python set-date.py 
Enter date and time in format 11/1/2011 1600
stdout: 'Tue Jan 11 16:00:00 EST 2011\n'
*******************************************************************************
stderr: ''
```

Comment: Thanks a million for breaking it down, and reminding me of validation.